# How to scale down bootstrap card image to initial size during hover?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Im working on a bootstrap card using HTML, CSS and Bootstrap.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to scale down the image during hover. I have a predefined height of `150px` on the `.card-header-img` which I don't want to change. I simply want during hover action, to scale down the image to the initial image size ensuring the the image is fully visible ***(both in width and height)***!

I would prefer if there is no `JavaScript` involved in this solution. I have already tried the following which doesn't seem to be working:

```
transform: scale(1, calc(150px / var(--initial-height)));
```

```css
.acf-blocksy-child-container {
  width: 70%;
}

.card-header-img {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  /* Predefined height */
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-header-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Ensure the image covers the entire container */
  transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card-header-img::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  /* Dark overlay */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.card-header-img:hover img {
  /* Scale down the image on hover */
  transform: scale(0.7);
  /* Scale down the image on hover 
    transform: scale(1.2); 
  */
  /* Scale down the image on hover 
  transform: scale(1, calc(150px / var(--initial-height)));
  */
}

.card-header-img:hover::before {
  opacity: 0;
  /* Dark overlay disappears on hover */
}

.card-header-img:hover .card-title,
.card-header-img:hover .card-text {
  display: none;
  /* Hide title and text on hover */
}
```

```html
<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
<div class='container-fluid acf-blocksy-child-container'>
  <div class='row'>
    <div class='col-md-12 mt-5'>
      <div class='card'>
        <!-- CARD HEADER -->
        <div class='card-header card-header-img' style='--initial-height: 250px'>
          <img src='https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/07/08/long-neck-giraffe-height-measure-vector-12290708.jpg' class='card-img img-fluid' alt='Card image'>
          <div class='card-img-overlay'>
            <h5 class='card-title text-white'>Card title</h5>
            <p class='card-text text-white'>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
            <p class='card-text text-white'>Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: _"I have already tried the following which doesn't seem to be working: `transform: scale(1, calc(250px / var(--initial-height)));`"_ - what is `--initial-height` supposed to be here, I don't see a CSS variable of that name anywhere else in what you have shown.

Comment: You won't be able to use object-fit and transition properly, you can take a look here: v

Comment: Hi @VincentDecaux it seems like you missed pasting a link !?

Comment: @CBroe any idea where i need to define it?

Comment: No, how would I. _You_ said you tried this - so what was that attempt based on to begin with?

Comment: You are right? I edited the question. i completely missed pasting that: `<div class='card-header card-header-img' style='--initial-height: 250px'>`

Comment: odd place to define that variable IMHO - most often they are IN the CSS.

Comment: That's not the purpose of this question. Despite that thanks for your comments, I was able to answer my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to declare a css variable for this. You just need to define the image with `width: 100%` and `height: 150px` or any other preffered value.

Then during hover action just change the width to `width: auto` this will automatically change the image ensuring fit!

`margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; display: block;`
are used to centrally align the image

**Here is full code snippet:**

```css
.card-header-img {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.card-header-img img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  object-fit: cover;
  /* Ensure the image covers the entire container */
  transition: transform 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-header-img::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  /* Dark overlay */
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

.card-header-img:hover img {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}

.card-header-img:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  /* Dark overlay disappears on hover */
}

.card-header-img:hover .card-title,
.card-header-img:hover .card-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<link href='https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>


<div class='card-header card-header-img'>
  <img src='https://cdn4.vectorstock.com/i/1000x1000/07/08/long-neck-giraffe-height-measure-vector-12290708.jpg' class='card-img img-fluid' alt='Card image'>
  <div class='card-img-overlay'>
    <h5 class='card-title text-white'>Card title</h5>
    <p class='card-text text-white'>This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
    <p class='card-text text-white'>Last updated 3 mins ago</p>
  </div>
</div>
```